# Avoiding dangling text when wrapping around a float

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

The image says it best:

[image]

It's simply a `float: left` image (http://jsbin.com/itihes/1). Is there any way to prevent this problem with dynamic text in pure CSS? I do want the text to wrap, but if it's less than one full row (ideally two full rows), all the text would stay in the same block on the right.

The image width is fixed, but the whole block's width is dynamic.

Comment: Why don't you put the text in a div and float both the div and the image to the left?

Comment: @Antony Because he wants it fall under the image if there is enough text left. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/itihes/3/edit - Not 100% dynamic since it relies on the image width.

Comment: Something to consider - many people increase the text size in their browsers. No matter what you do to correct this you'll find there are still many who could get the dangling text.

Comment: @KaiQing If there's any genius solution to this, it would already take into account the dynamic width, so font size shouldn't be any more of an issue.

Comment: @mahemoff - you can't reliably assume any genius solution factors in all scenarios. Safe to say it is still a consideration that many people just overlook.

Comment: I'm just saying that font size isn't an extra consideration here. Any solution that works for variable width would also work for font size.

Answer (score 2):

DSKrepps got a point : The closest thing you can do is paragraph-by-paragraph on each

tag, such that the remaining text of that paragraph doesn't wrap but the next paragraph is full width.

What you'll do is smthing like this

```
.text-div p:first-child {
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:(a number matching (img height + bottom margin) divider)
}
```

this way, your first paragraph wont wrap under .. but the other `<p>` will

jsfiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/6FQuH/

otherwise --> javascript

Answer (score 1):

So, you want the text to wrap only if it is long enough to not look orphaned below the photo.

Unfortunately this isn't possible with CSS alone. The closest thing you can do is paragraph-by-paragraph on each `<p>` tag, such that the remaining text of that paragraph doesn't wrap but the next paragraph is full width. Like so: http://jsbin.com/avogil/1/edit

Of course it is also possible with Javascript, by comparing the sizes of the floated image with that of the paragraph and comparing the difference to the font size. You'd probably want to use jQuery.

Perhaps a future CSS spec might address this case someday.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do in this situation is bump up the margin-bottom of the image to approx. twice the font-size.  12px font size, 24px margin bottom.  You can still have an orphan, but in the above case, the text would remain inline, without wrapping down, and for much longer text, it would wrap properly.  It leaves a small window where you could still have a single line orphan.

Comment: Why would that work?  Doesn't it just change the point at which you get the dangling line of text?  Certainly that's what seems to happen when I try this.